# Batch file run as administrator not working while set in task scheduler

Tags: windows-8, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I have a `.bat` file for getting latest from TFS and set a scheduler to run every day but what my problem is some of the folder needs Administrator privilege to update so need to `.bat` file as run as Administrator.

**What i have tries so Far...**

Create shortcut and than set this `.bat` shortcut file and in advance option i have set this to `Run As Administrator` and set it in scheduler action but not working it's still showing me error `Access denied` but when i right click and and run this as administrator it'll work any help or suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure the following settings? You should use the same administrator account.

[image]

Comment: Thanx for your reply i'll do dat and check :)